# Why is Insertion Sort faster than Bubble Sort and Heap Sort in practice?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have seen in the link(http://bigocheatsheet.com/) the complexity for insertion sort is same as bubble sort, and also heap sort is better than both these two. But when I created a sample program and compared the time taken insertion sort is unbelievable.

Class Used to test the sorting algorithms.

```
public class TestSorts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting");
        Calendar startInstance = null;
        Calendar endInstance = null;

        //Getting the array to sort
        startInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        //int[] arrayToSort = ArrayClass.getArray(1000);
        int[] arrayToSort = ArrayClass.getWorstArray(10000000);
        endInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        long timeTakenToGetArray = endInstance.getTimeInMillis()- startInstance.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("StartTime : "+startInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("EndTime : "+endInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("TimeTakenToGetArray : "+timeTakenToGetArray);

        //Bubble Sort       
        startInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        int[] bubbleSorted = BubbleSort.sort(arrayToSort);
        endInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        long timeTakenBubble = endInstance.getTimeInMillis() - startInstance.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("StartTime : "+startInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("EndTime : "+endInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("Bubble : "+timeTakenBubble);

        //InsertionSort
        startInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        int[] insertionSorted = InsertionSort.sort(arrayToSort);
        endInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        long timeTakenInsertion = endInstance.getTimeInMillis() - startInstance.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("StartTime : "+startInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("EndTime : "+endInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("Insertion : "+timeTakenInsertion);

        //HeapSort
        startInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        int[] heapSorted = HeapSort.sort(arrayToSort);
        endInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        long timeTakenHeap = endInstance.getTimeInMillis() - startInstance.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("StartTime : "+startInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("EndTime : "+endInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("Heap : "+timeTakenHeap);

        startInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        arraysAreEqual(bubbleSorted, insertionSorted, heapSorted);
        endInstance= Calendar.getInstance();
        long timeTakenToCompare = endInstance.getTimeInMillis() - startInstance.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("StartTime : "+startInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("EndTime : "+endInstance.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println("TimeTakenToCompare : "+timeTakenToCompare);

    }



    //Method to compare whether the sorted arrays are equal
    static void arraysAreEqual(int[] bubbleSorted,int[] insertionSorted,int[] heapSorted)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<bubbleSorted.length;i++)
        {
            if((bubbleSorted[i]!=insertionSorted[i])||(heapSorted[i]!=insertionSorted[i])||(heapSorted[i]!=bubbleSorted[i]))
            {
                System.out.println("Bubble : "+bubbleSorted[i]);
                System.out.println("Insertion : "+insertionSorted[i]);
                System.out.println("Heap : "+heapSorted[i]);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Class for **Bubble Sort**

```
public class BubbleSort {

    static int[] sort(int[] arrayToSort)
    {
        int length = arrayToSort.length;
        for(int i = 0;i<length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1;j<length;j++)
            {
                if(arrayToSort[i]>arrayToSort[j])
                {
                    arrayToSort[i]+=arrayToSort[j];
                    arrayToSort[j] = arrayToSort[i] - arrayToSort[j];
                    arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[i] - arrayToSort[j];
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayToSort;
    }

}
```

Class For **Insert Sort**

```
public class InsertionSort {

    static int[] sort(int[] arrayToSort)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSort.length; i++) {  
               int value = arrayToSort[i];  
               int j = i - 1;  
               while (j >= 0 && arrayToSort[j] > value) {  
                   arrayToSort[j + 1] = arrayToSort[j];  
                j = j - 1;  
               }  
               arrayToSort[j + 1] = value;  

              }  
         return arrayToSort;
    }

}
```

Class for **Heap Sort**

```
public class HeapSort {

    static int a[];
    static int[] sort(int[] arrayToSort)
    {
        a = arrayToSort;

        heapsort();
        return a;
    }
    static void heapsort()
    {

        int size = a.length; 
        maxHeapify(size);
        for(int i =a.length-1;i>=1;i--)
        {
            swap(0,i);
            size--;
            maxHeapify(size);
        }
    }
    static void maxHeapify(int size)
    {
        for(int i =size/2-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            heapify(i,size);
        }
    }


    static void heapify(int i,int size)
    {
        int left = 2*i+1;
        int right = 2*i+2;
        int max = i;
        if(left<size&&a[left]>a[i])
        {
            max = left;
        }
        if(right<size&&a[right]>a[max])
        {
            max = right;
        }
        if(max!=i)
        {
            swap(i,max);
            heapify(max,size);
        }

    }
    static void swap(int i,int j)
    {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

}
```

The class for creating the array

```
import java.util.Random;


public class ArrayClass {

    public static int[] getArray(int size)
    {
        int array[] = new int[size];

        for(int i =0;i<size;i++)
        {
            int s = randomInt(10,size);

            array[i] = s;

        }

        return array;
    }

    private static int randomInt(int min,int max)
    {
        Random rn = new Random();

        int randomNumber = rn.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

        return randomNumber;
    }

    public static int[] getBestArray(int size)
    {
        int array[] = new int[size];
        for(int i =0;i<size;i++)
        {
            array[i]=i+1;
        }
        return array;

    }
    public static int[] getWorstArray(int size)
    {
        int array[] = new int[size];
        for(int i =size-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            array[i]=i;
        }
        return array;

    }

}
```

I tried all scenarios like best case, worst case and average case. But in all case Insertion sort is very much faster compared to bubble and heap sort. Theoretically heap sort is supposed to be the best in case of worst scenario.

Please find the below test result when I used 100000 as the input for a worst case scenario.

```
starting
StartTime : 1413470225347
EndTime : 1413470225362
TimeTakenToGetArray : 15
StartTime : 1413470225362
EndTime : 1413470226894
Bubble : 1532
StartTime : 1413470226894
EndTime : 1413470226896
Insertion : 2
StartTime : 1413470226896
EndTime : 1413470233474
Heap : 6578
StartTime : 1413470233474
EndTime : 1413470233488
TimeTakenToCompare : 14
```

Can you please let me know why insertion sort is giving faster output than heap sort ?

Comment: Also, it is entirely possible that the JIT compiler is using your benchmarking harness to defeat your benchmark.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Comment: What is `getWorstArray` supposed to do? Filling it in reverse doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs:

- Your `BubbleSort` sorts the array (in place!), then you pass that same array to the next method (`InsertionSort`).
- `getWorstArray` is returning a sorted array. Running the loop in the other direction won't change the order of the elements. And anyway, you're using a corner case (sorted, reverse sorted, doesn't matter) and your results will be biased.
- A good `BubbleSort` has early termination (if no swaps were made during the scan, it's sorted).

At this point, I would question the rest of the code. Bugs usually come in clusters (bad day, inexperienced programmer, ...). Check for more bugs. Do unit tests.

Comment: BubbleSort is O(n) for sorted arrays.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen The array isn't sorted when BubbleSort sees it.  It is sorted by the time InsertionSort gets to it. Thus BubbleSort gets no advantage for its timing, while InsertionSort reaps the benefit.

Comment: amended all the comments.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath Thank you for correcting the issues. Now I am getting the result I expected. The issues are due to my in experience. Sorry for the trouble :(

Answer (score 2):

Your sort methods are actually sorting the original array, and InsertionSort is O(n) for an already sorted list. Since you do BubbleSort first, you've given InsertionSort an unfair advantage.

For a fairer comparison you should make identical copies of the original array (outside the timing), and hand each sort routine a separate copy. That way you get head-to-head comparisons with the same input.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion Sorts can be faster than other Sorts for small lists because they place each item in it's right place within the first iteration(loop). What slows it down is shifting everything out of it's way to do the insert. This is why the list must be small.